# Use an input variable inside a formula in macro

Tags: variables, excel, input, excel-formula, vba

I want to use a user input inside a formula as follows:

```
Sub example()

Dim StockDays As Integer
StockDays = InputBox(Prompt:="How many days?")

Range("AG2").FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUNDUP(RC[-6]*" & StockDays & "/90, 0)"
Range("AG2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 33), Cells(1500, 33))

End Sub
```

When run, the above code throws an error at the ROUNDUP line.

> Run-time error 1004.
>   Application-defined or object-defined error.

I think the problem is related to the variable `StockDays`.

How can I arrange the code so that I can make it work?

Comment: Your formula looks perfect - I would hazard a guess at saying it has nothing to do with the `StockDays` part and that you haven't referenced a sheet or something like that. Try `Sheets(1).Range("AG2")` kind of notation instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have commented the code so you shouldn't have any problem understanding it :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub example()
    Dim StockDays As Integer

    '~~> Type:=1  will ensure that the user enters only numbers
    StockDays = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many days?", Type:=1)

    '~~> No Need to autofill. You can fill all the range in one go
    Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AG2:AG1500").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=ROUNDUP(RC[-6] * " & StockDays & "/ 90, 0)"

    'OR this as mentioned in your comment

    Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AG2:AG1500").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=ROUNDUP((RC[-6]* " & StockDays & "/90),0)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but this gives the same error in my question. What could be wrong?

Comment: Have updated the code. Try it now. Replace "Sheet1" with the relevant sheetname. Replace `Thisworkbook` if you are trying to run the code on another workbook. Also ensure that the worksheet is not protected.

Comment: I've found out that the problem is originated from the parentheses. I didn't expect that.

Comment: The correct form is: `"=ROUNDUP((RC[-6]* " & StockDays & "/90),0)"`. Could you please update your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I have amended the code above but that shouldn't be the reason why you should be getting the errors because of that....

Comment: I also think that it shouldn't be the reason, but strangely, the code works on my machine in this way... I tried this on another machine and the same thing happened... Anyway, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

Range("AG2").FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUNDUP(RC[-6] * `" & StockDays & "` / 90, 0)"

the mistake u did was, you where applying a formula but forgot to replace the variable u used with the value in the varaiable

Comment: i tried it and it generated some output as expected `=ROUNDUP(B36*12/ 90, 0)`

Comment: if it is still not working can you please paste here what error you get with this code

Comment: not sure why you are getting the error, i tried your code with just a small change (`Range("H2")`) and it is working fine